# What is the best way to store and play back XML nodes?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, memory-management, xmlreader

I have some XML that looks like this (highly simplified):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<example>
    <shortcuts>
        <shortcut name="shortcut1">
            <property name="name1" value="value1" />
            <property name="name2" value="value2" />
        </shortcut>
    </shortcuts>
    <data>
        <datum name="datum1">
            <property name="name1" value="value1" />
            <property name="name2" value="value2" />    
        </datum>
        <datum name="datum2">
            <shortcutRef name="shortcut1" />
        </datum>
        <datum name="datum3">
            <shortcutRef name="shortcut1" />
            <property name="name3" value="value3" />    
        </datum>
    </data>
</example>
```

As you can see, it is structured such that "shortcuts" can be defined which consist of one or more properties. Data can then be described explicitly with properties, or one or more shortcuts, or a mix of both (and there is no specific order).

I want to parse this with XmlReader (XmlDocument would be easier but won't work here because the XML file is too large). I thought a good way to do this would be to store XML subtrees of each shortcut in a dictionary keyed by the shortcut names, which are unique. Then when they are referenced, I could just read through that subtree XmlReader rather than the main one. However the subtree XmlReader must still be linked to the main XmlReader because the XML that comes out is not what I expect. Here is my code:

```
using(XmlReader xml = XmlReader.Create("example.xml"))
{
    Dictionary<string, XmlReader> shortcuts = new Dictionary<string, XmlReader>();
    xml.ReadToDescendant("shortcuts");
    xml.ReadToDescendant("shortcut");
    do
    {
        shortcuts.Add(xml.GetAttribute("name"), xml.ReadSubtree());
    } while(xml.ReadToNextSibling("shortcut"));

    xml.ReadToFollowing("data");
    while(xml.ReadToFollowing("datum"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(xml.GetAttribute("name"));

        XmlReader datum = xml.ReadSubtree();
        while(datum.Read())
        {
            if(datum.Name == "property")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(datum.GetAttribute("name") + ':' + datum.GetAttribute("value"));
            }
            else if(datum.Name == "shortcutRef")
            {
                XmlReader shortcut_ref = shortcuts[datum.GetAttribute("name")];
                while(shortcut_ref.ReadToFollowing("property"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(shortcut_ref.GetAttribute("name") + ':' + shortcut_ref.GetAttribute("value"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to parse XML that is structured in this way?

Comment: What is the preferred output data structure (i.e. the result of parsing)?

Comment: At this point I'd just like to be able to parse the name and value of every property associated with each datum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not entirely clear what you want to do – but since you use the words “play back”  then I am guessing you don’t need to store ALL the values from the XML nodes (data / datum) in memory (you can discard them after use), however you need to cache the shortcut properties so that you can re-iterate through them when they are referenced… You just about had it, but instead of storing the XML nodes, just store the objects instead in the dictionary.

```
public class Property
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Shortcut
{
    public List<Property> Properties = new List<Property>();
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\example.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fs);

        Dictionary<string, Shortcut> ShortcutDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Shortcut>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName == "shortcuts")
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName == "shortcut")
                    {
                        Shortcut shortcut = new Shortcut();
                        ShortcutDictionary.Add(reader.GetAttribute("name"), shortcut);
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName == "property")
                                shortcut.Properties.Add(new Property() { Name = reader.GetAttribute("name"), Value = reader.GetAttribute("value") });
                            else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement && reader.LocalName == "shortcut")
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement && reader.LocalName == "shortcuts")
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName == "data")
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName == "datum")
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName == "property")
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(reader.GetAttribute("name") + ':' + reader.GetAttribute("value"));
                            }
                            else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName == "shortcutRef")
                            {
                                foreach (Property property in ShortcutDictionary[reader.GetAttribute("name")].Properties)
                                    Console.WriteLine(property.Name + ':' + property.Value);
                            }
                            else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement && reader.LocalName == "datum")
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement && reader.LocalName == "data")
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        reader.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if that is not it, then you are trying to access serial data in a random access manner.  Your best bet would be to convert/save the data into a database.  Something like SQLite would do it.

Comment: I was hoping for an answer where it was very seamless between iterating through properties from shortcuts versus the explicit properties, to minimize the amount of code required. But this does meet all my requirements so you get the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

You might use LinqToXml as Mathieson suggests.  Here's an example of using a lookup.

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file); // or .Parse(string)
var shortcuts = root.Descendants("shortcut").SelectMany(s =>
    s.Elements("property").ToLookup(
        k => k.Parent.Attribute("name").Value,
        v => v.Select(p => new
        {
            Name = p.Attribute("name").Value,
            Value = p.Attribute("value").Value
        })));
```

This will result in a dictionary like structure, but a lookup has multiple values for a key.  So you will have a lookup of all the properties by shortcut name.

Comment: Won't that have the same memory issues as XmlDocument?

Comment: what kind of memory issues?  I assure you it isn't going to leak memory

Comment: also if you have concerns, you should ask a separate question about memory and the various xml readers.

Comment: The XML files are huge--currently up to a gig and they could get larger in the future. Loading all that into memory can be prohibitive. I assume there has to be a way to do this with XmlReader.

Comment: I use the same technique you are using for data lookups in my XML files.  While the size is only around 1MB, it is lightning fast.  You can create functions that return your looked up data by passing the select list variable as an XElement argument.  If you need more of an answer, let me know.

Answer (score -1):

I'd use xml serialization. Just create a POCO Class with the structure you want (in this case, an "exemple" class with a list of "data" and "shortcuts"), annotate some  members so they can render as attribute and call xml serialize. Check this out:

how to create class: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part-1

how to serialize and deserialize: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/347758/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization

Answer (score -2):

Generally parsing XML files could be done throw two main sane ways: 
 1. **DOM** (Document Object Model) 
 2. **SAX** (Simple API for XML)

**Differences**:
A DOM parser creates a tree structure in memory from the input document and then waits for requests from client. But a SAX parser does not create any internal structure. Instead, it takes the occurrences of components of a input document as events, and tells the client what it reads as it reads through the input document. 
A DOM parser always serves the client application with the entire document no matter how much is actually needed by the client but a SAX parser serves the client application always only with pieces of the document at any given time.
With DOM parser, method calls in client application have to be explicit and forms a kind of chain. But with SAX, some certain methods (usually overriden by the cient) will be invoked automatically (implicitly) in a way which is called "callback" when some certain events occur. 
These methods do not have to be called explicitly by the client, though we could call them explicitly.

***DOM*** 
1. Tree of nodes
2. Memory: Occupies more memory, preffered for small XML documents
3. Slower at runtime 
4. Stored as objects 
5. Programmatically easy 
6. Ease of navigation 
***SAX*** 
1. Sequence of events 
2. Doesn't use any memory preferred for large documents
3. Faster at runtime
4. Objects are to be created
5. Need to write code for creating objects
6. Backward navigation is not possible as it sequentially processes the document

**Implementation .Net framework**:
*`XmlReader`*(some how)  and *`XmlDocuments`* are constructed based on DOM model, [MSDN refrence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478996.aspx).
I havent found an official .Net framework API for SAX but you may use [Towards a Declarative SAX Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6976/Towards-a-Declarative-SAX-Framework-Part-1-A-Simpl) or [Sax for .Net](http://saxdotnet.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: -1 Doesn't answer the question asked, the OP knows the difference between SAX and DOM, he is just wondering how to do this one task with  SAX since the file size is too large for DOM.